# How to give an output directory in maven bundle plugin

Tags: java, maven, wso2, osgi-bundle

I started creating an OSGI bundle. So It works fine. But when I put output directory in configuration section in maven bundle plugin, it won't add any of compiled classes. simply say, the classpath is empty.I am also using maven compiler plugin. Are they conflicting each other? Is there anything which I configured in a wrong way. This is the build section of my pox.xml file.

```
  <build>
  <plugins>

      <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1</version>
          <configuration>
              <source>1.7</source>
              <target>1.7</target>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.4.0</version>
          <extensions>true</extensions>
          <configuration>
              <instructions>
                  <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                  <Bundle-Name>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-Name>
                  <Export-Package>
                      demo.wso2.orderprocess.*
                  </Export-Package>
              </instructions>
              <outputDirectory>/home/wso2/product/wso2esb-4.9.0/repository/components/dropins</outputDirectory>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>

  </plugins>
```

Comment: I haven't tried. but this might be a bug in the plugin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964391/output-directory-for-maven-bundle-plugin and also refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943392/classpath-empty-when-adding-outputdirectory-to-pom

Comment: Yeap I saw that. There should be a way to do this. Shouldn't be?

Comment: May be you can check the maven source :)

Comment: I didn't mean in that way :) . Final task is to deploy bundle in desired location. I am new to maven so let's see

Comment: ;) check the last comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943392/classpath-empty-when-adding-outputdirectory-to-pom
"But when I changed ${project.build.outputDirectory} to an absolute path, it worked."
better give a try

Comment: Thanks, I'll let you know

Comment: No luck with that either

Comment: But I can see <parameter>
          <name>outputDirectory</name>
          <type>java.io.File</type>
          <required>true</required>
          <editable>true</editable>
          <description>The directory for the generated bundles.</description>
        </parameter> this in the plugin.xml.  Also in the maven-model-builder-3.0.5.jar!/org/apache/maven/model/pom-4.0.0.xml,  output directory is definefd as this way <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `<buildDirectory>/home/wso2/product/wso2esb-4.9.0/repository/components/dropins</buildDirectory>` instead of `<outputDirectory>/home/wso2/product/wso2esb-4.9.0/repository/components/dropins</outputDirectory>`. It did the trick for me, so now I can increase the speed of the OSGI bundles development!

**Reference:**
[Maven Bundle Plugin documentation](http://felix.apache.org/components/bundle-plugin/instructions-mojo.html#buildDirectory)

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I did to get around the issue and it worked!!!

Keep your project packaging type as "jar" and add OSGI metadata to it. This can be achieved by adding an execution goal to the *maven-bundle-plugin* and referencing it from *maven-jar-plugin*. Now, just add the **outputDirectory** path into the *maven-jar-plugin* where you want to place the jar.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <archive>  
      <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
    </archive> 
  </configuration>
  <outputDirectory>/path/to/output/directory</outputDirectory>
</plugin>  
<plugin>   
  <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>bundle-manifest</id>
      <phase>process-classes</phase>
      <goals>    
        <goal>manifest</goal>
      </goals>   
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Now, to build the project, run the following command. This will generate the manifest file and package it into jar.

```
mvn org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:manifest install
```

**Reference:**

[Apache Felix Documentation](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html#adding-osgi-metadata-to-existing-projects-without-changing-the-packaging-type)